# Developing a Firefox extension for Google Calendar

Tags: firefox-addon, google-calendar-api

I am actually not so sure if it is possible but It would be great for me to have a firefox add-on to add/remove/edit/delete for google calendar.

Is there any blog entry or a reference documents about this ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [JavaScript version of the GData v1.0 protocol](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/1.0/developers_guide_js.html). Currently v2.0 is only supported in .NET and Java by the looks of it, but I'd expect v1.0 to still work.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you'll have to understand [Google Calendar's API](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/), and [Firefox plug-in API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Building_an_Extension).  Links go to information about both.  Google can provide more information.

It should be possible, though.  There are plenty of other applications out there that link into Calendar.